# Why does Kotlin Iterable minus operator returns only a result without the first occurrence of a single element operand?

Tags: kotlin, operators

```
public operator fun <T> Iterable<T>.minus(element: T): List<T>
```

> Returns a list containing all elements of the original collection without the first occurrence of the given [element].

This means that subtracting a single item gives a different result from subtracting a list of the same item.

So

```
assertEquals(listOf(2, 1), listOf(1, 2, 1) - 1)
```

whereas

```
assertEquals(listOf(2), listOf(1, 2, 1) - listOf(1))
```

which seems strange. Why the discrepancy?
By which I mean, why does the element version remove only the first match, but the list version remove every match.

Comment: Without a canonical answer from the designers, we can only guess. But the minus(list) version would be hard to describe and reason about if its algorithm somehow had the result of removing only first occurrences of items. Like, what would happen if an item appears multiple times in one or both lists? As it stands now, it is quite simple: subtracting an item removes one item, subtracting a collection removes everything that appears in the collection and is just like `filterNot` with `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example uses a different implementation of the `minus` operator - one that takes an `Iterable<T>` as a parameter, the doc is pretty clear on the difference:

```kotlin
/**
 * Returns a list containing all elements of the original collection except the elements contained in the given [elements] collection.
 * 
 * The [elements] collection may be converted to a [HashSet] to speed up the operation, thus the elements are required to have
 * a correct and stable implementation of `hashCode()` that doesn't change between successive invocations.
 */
public operator fun <T> Iterable<T>.minus(elements: Iterable<T>): List<T>
```

See also: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html

I guess you could argue that the semantics of the `.minus(element: T)` are so different from those of  `.minus(elements: Iterable<T>)` (and other "collection-like" types) as to justify a different function name. Looks like the library designers didn't think that was an issue.

Comment: Ah thanks for being confused - I’ve updated my question to try to make it clearer